# java: How to read data coming to the particular socket port?

Tags: java

I have a GPS device which is sending a GPS data to my machine port but I'm not sure which is the best way to read the data coming at that particular socket.

Please help me to get this done.
Thank you and Have a nice day.

Comment: Look at Java Sockets if it's about TCP: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to read write from socket

```
Socket echoSocket = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
 try {
       echoSocket = new Socket("taranis", 7);
       out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
       in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        echoSocket.getInputStream()));
      } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                             + "the connection to: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
            }
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    echoSocket.close();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, There is "AVL data coding" and the device is using "FM4XXX DATA PROTOCOL" and sending the packets in this format, of Teltonika.

Answer (score 0):

For a good network application framework you can look at Apache Mina (http://mina.apache.org/), we are using Mina to receive and send data from various GPS devices.
In which format does your data come in, ASCII?

Comment: Hi, There is "AVL data coding" and the device is using "FM4XXX DATA PROTOCOL" of Teltonika.